# discrete cosine transform

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For what sort of 1-D signals (single variable, mathematical functions), DCT does not do 'energy compaction'?  Surely, if you take 'all-ones' signal and take 1D-IDCT you would get the answer.  That means for such signals, DCT does not do 'energy compaction'.  Can we say for such signals, DCT does 'energy expansion'.  Are there some general observations about such signals for which DCT does energy expansion rather compaction?  The same can be said/asked about 2-D signals and 2-D DCT.

Comment: A multidimensional DCT separates into 1d DCT's along the coordinate axes. Do you even know what "energy compactation" means? Also, the discrete-mathematics tag is inappropriate.

Comment: Energy compaction means the concentration of the result from the transform in a few coeffs compared to the original function.  That is how I understand.  Obviously, I did not understand it fully.  That is why I asked.  I think they are related but I agree that signal processing is more appropriate.  I will ask the question there.